# How do I make a hyperlink to a Google Calendar event i just created?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Im using Google App Script and have created an event in google calendars...

```
  var createdEvent = myCal.createEvent(title, starttime, endtime, {description: notes, guests: cal.getId(), location: cal.getName()});

 var eventID = createdEvent.getId();
```

I am trying to now create a hyperlink to the event I just created. Does anyone know how I can do this? I've been searching all over google search engine and GAS documentation but cant find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553846/get-link-url-to-an-calendar-event-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this I have managed to do it using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/) and it reads the google calendar and you can click on the events as hyperlinks:

Use this:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=800,height=700');
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                return false;
            },
```