# Creating a URL to a Google Calendar Event using its Event ID in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is to use the Google Calendar Event ID in my sheet and to create a link to refer the user to the event by simply clicking on it.

I have successfully written a script that imports various information about a Google Calendar event into a spreadsheet. This includes information about BeginDate, EndDate, BeginHour, EndHour, NameOfCreator, EmailOfCreator, EventTitle and especially the Event ID.

My Event ID has the following format:
1c0tqtn56c1tdo1i0fus66f53g@google.com

Unfortunately I haven't managed to create a usable URL yet. Other forum entries have an ID (which had a different format) decoded with Base64. Unfortunately this doesn't work. How could I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The event object already has the link within it, you can access it with `var url = event.htmlLink;` it will give you the URL as a string, and you can simply write it into the sheet for your users.

If that does not work, you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33302612/11581830) to craft it yourself.